# Математика, алгебра, геометрия и прочие математические науки

Tags: математика

Всем привет, я начинающий программист. Всегда мечтал стать инженером в отрасли ИБ. Сис.админ, хацкер и т.д. Увлекаться компьютерами начал еще в 5 лет, когда мама впервые дала посидеть за ноутбуком. Постепенно начал вникать в суть, но забросил это дело. Сейчас мне 16 лет, я хочу подтянуть математику, так как она мне наверняка пригодится. Но дело в том, что интерес есть, а что делать не знаю. В школе плохо преподавали, пробелов много. Может кто шарит в этой области и решают мат.книги как семечки. Посоветуйте пожалуйста с чего начать?

Comment: Да не нужна эта математика. Учил-учил в институте, хоть бы что пригодилось.

Comment: Изучайте алгоритмы и структуры данных. А также английский язык.

Comment: Найди лекции по математике на youtube. Там полно хороших школьных учителей, которые отлично объясняют (до меня дошли некоторые вещи спустя 20 лет)). Но дам ещё пару советов. Английский учи в любом случае, будешь ты прогером, или нет. Пройди профориентацию это поможет спрямить жизненное направление, а то будет как у @Эникейщик, да и у меня собственно, также))